# How can I change the footer on all of my pages from one document?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

It's kind of hard to make a title for my question, sorry if it doesn't make sense. I'm trying to make a navbar and footer (for my bootstrap website) but I want to be able to make changes to every page but only have one document. For example if I place the navigation bar in every page of the website, then change the about me page to about, I don't want to go through 100 pages to do so. Any ideas?

Comment: You'd normally include a file either from the server (e.g. PHP) or using JavaScript to render the content and then just change the included file once to have the changes made on any file that uses it. If you're just hard coding plain HTML then there's no simple answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking, probably you have little or no knowledge of PHP or other Server Side scripting languages; if you want to avoid Javascript too, the best solution, simple and effective, are IFRAMEs.

1) Put the content to "repeat" into the pages into a specific `content_to_be_repeated.html`
2) Add this where you need to place the content itself for each page:

```
 <iframe src="http://www.content_to_be_repeated.html"  width="..." height="..."></iframe>
```

Adjoust the width and height attributes in pixel (or wathever) accordling with your needs.

Probably you would like to get rid of the iframe default scrollbars, so:

```
<iframe src="http://www.content_to_be_repeated.html"  width="..." height="..." scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

Now it comes that scrolling attribut has been deprecated since HTML 5, (it will anyway work); neverthless it would be better writing this way:

```
<iframe src="http://www.content_to_be_repeated.html"  width="..." height="..." style="overflow: hidden;"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider you are using PHP

index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
<title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>

<!-- Bootstrap -->
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js">    </script>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
include '../master/header.php';

 <h1>Hello, world!</h1>

<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
include '../master/footer.php';
</body>
</html>
```

Here you can goto your Master folder and create your web site header and footer

Answer (score 0):

If you're using hardcoded HTML and don't have access to a server (i.e. you can't use PHP) you can use jQuery's [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/):

Your `index.html`:

```
<div id="header">
</div>
<!-- your content here -->
<div id="footer">
</div>
<script src="/path/to/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/scripts.js"></script>
```

Your `scripts.js`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#header').load('/header.html');
  $('#footer').load('/footer.html');
});
```

Your `header.html`:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <!-- bootstrap navbar code here -->
</nav>
```

Your `footer.html`:

```
<footer>
  <p class="text-center">&copy; 2015 Your Company</p>
  <!-- your footer content here -->
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

With PHP :)

Have a php file eg "navigation.php",

In "navigation.php":

```
<?php
//Open your function
function footer() {
//Note php closing tag below
?>

<div class="footer">
//Place your footer content as plain HTML,
</div>

<?php
//Close your function
}
?>
```

Now in your display page, lets call it "index.php",

In "index.php"

```
//Near the top of your .php file, "index.php" in this case
<?php
include(path/to/navigation.php);
?>

<?php
//This will return the contents of our footer function above 
//place this where you require your footer, note the php tags
footer();
?>
```